# onClick() Javascript function not being recognized, ReferenceError: function is not defined, using document Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've read all the other cases and I didn't have any luck. I'm doing my own jQuery grid. I'm trying to trigger a function when a save button is clicked(other jQuery functions are working)..... Here's where I include the Javascript file "newsletter.js"...The jQuery and bootstrap files are being loaded by the configuration file on PHP symfony 1.4 for that module...

```
<body><div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-7-bc">

              
    <h3 style="font-size:20px"> JURISPRUDENCIA</h3>

    <p>

        </br>

    </p>
  
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item ico "><a id="newsletters" target="_blank">Newsletters |</a></div>
        
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item ico "><a  id="fallos" target="_blank">Navegar |</a></div>

       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item ico"><a id="cuadernos_mpd" target="_blank">Cuadernos del MPD</a></div>
     
        
       <div id="grilla"></div>
      



</div>

<?php use_javascript("jurisprudencia/newsletter.js");
     use_javascript("jurisprudencia/funciones_grilla.js");
?>
```

Here's my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    //API methods newsletters
    //guardar
    
    function guardarNewsletter(id){

        alert(id);

        /*$("#fieldset_"+id).show();
        $("#fieldset_hidden_"+id).hide();
        
        
            
             $.ajax({
                  url:"/newsletter/guardarNewsletter", 
                  data: newsletter.serialize(), 
                  success:function(data) {
                     alert("Row Guardada"); 
                  }
               });*/
        
    }
    
    
    $("#newsletters").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("/newsletter/getNewsletters", function(result){
            
            var grid="<br><table id='newsletter_grid'>";
            grid+="<thead><tr><th></th><th>Año</th><th>Mes</th><th>Quincena</th><th></th><th></th><th>Publicado</th></tr></thead>";
            
             grid+="<tr><td><button id='agregar_button'>Nuevo</button></td></tr>";
            
             grid+="<tr id='nuevo_field' style='display:none'>";
             
             grid+=crearNuevaRow();
             
             grid+="</tr>";
     
                
             
            $.each(result, function(i, elem){
            
                //show view fieldset, son los campos que se muestran para visualizar los datos
                
                grid+="<tr id='fieldset_"+elem.id+"'>";
                            
                grid+=mostrarElementosViewMode(elem);               
            
                grid+="</tr>";
                
               
                //hidden field
                
                grid+="<tr id='fieldset_hidden_"+elem.id+"' style='display:none'>";
                
                grid+=crearRowHidden(elem);
            
                grid+="</tr>";
                
                
            });
            
            grid+="</table>";
            
            $("#grilla").html(grid);

            
        });
        
        
     
        
    }); 
    
    //crea los elementos editables con el value de su correspondiente existente en modo View o se usa para crear un elemento nuevo
    
    function crearRowHidden(elem){
        
        var nuevoHiddenFieldSet="";
        
        nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input type='hidden' value='"+elem.id+"'></td>";
        
        nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input name='anio' value='"+elem.anio+"'/></td>";
        
        nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input name='anio' value='"+elem.mes+"'/></td>";
        
        nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input name='quincena' value='"+elem.quincena+"'/></td>";
    
        nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><button value='Guardar' name='guardar_newsletter' id='guardar_newsletter_"+elem.id+"' onclick='guardarNewsletter("+elem.id+")'>Guardar</td>";
                
        nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td></td>";
        
        if(elem.publicado==1){
            nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='publicado_"+elem.id+"' name='publicado' checked='checked'></td>";
        }else{
            nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='publicado_"+elem.id+"' name='publicado'></td>";
        }
        return nuevoHiddenFieldSet;
     
    }
    
    function crearNuevaRow(){
        
        var nuevaRow="";
        
        nuevaRow+="<td><input type='hidden' value=''></td>";
        
        nuevaRow+="<td><input name='anio' value=''/></td>";
        
        nuevaRow+="<td><input name='anio' value=''/></td>";
        
        nuevaRow+="<td><input name='quincena' value=''/></td>";
    //ver que ponerle en id
        nuevaRow+="<td><button value='Guardar' name='guardar_newstletter' id=''>Guardar</td>";
                
        nuevaRow+="<td></td>";
        //ver que ponerle en id
        nuevaRow+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='' name='publicado'></td>";

        return nuevaRow;
        
    }
    
    //muestra los elementos del listado que se trae de la base de datos
    
    function mostrarElementosViewMode(elem){
        
        var elemento;
        
        elemento+="<td><input type='hidden' value='"+elem.id+"'></td>";
        
        elemento+="<td>"+elem.anio+"</td>";
        
        elemento+="<td>"+elem.mes+"</td>";
        
        elemento+="<td>"+elem.quincena+"</td>";
        
        elemento+="<td><button id='editar_"+elem.id+"' value='Editar' onclick='muestraEditarFields(\""+elem.id+"\")'>Editar</td>";
        
        elemento+="<td><button id='eliminar_newsletter_"+elem.id+"' value='Eliminar'>Eliminar</td>";
        
        if(elem.publicado == 1){
            elemento+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='publicado_"+elem.id+"' name='publicado' checked='checked'></td>";
        } else {
            elemento+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='publicado_"+elem.id+"' name='publicado'></td>";
        }
        
        return elemento;
        
    }
    
});
```

This is the part that doesn't work:

```
nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><button value='Guardar' name='guardar_newsletter' id='guardar_newsletter_"+elem.id+"' onclick='guardarNewsletter("+elem.id+")'>Guardar</td>";
```

I tried to use a jQuery click event and I keep getting the same error when I click the button, not the alert that should show up:

> ReferenceError: guardarNewsletter is not defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The edit button on this grid is working so I don't know why jQuery is not recognizing my function. I've read that could be a timing problem of when the function is being called, but I'm not sure in this case. Basically what I do is bring rows from the database, and create one for visualizing and one hidden for editing, the editing fields show up but when I want to save that error comes up. Any light on this matter?

Comment: The function's scope is isolated inside the document ready function and is not global. The onclick needs a global function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is defining the function but it is not available in global functions

```
function guardarNewsletter(id){

    alert(id);

    /*$("#fieldset_"+id).show();
    $("#fieldset_hidden_"+id).hide();



         $.ajax({
              url:"/newsletter/guardarNewsletter", 
              data: newsletter.serialize(), 
              success:function(data) {
                 alert("Row Guardada"); 
              }
           });*/

}
$(document).ready(function(){   

//API methods newsletters
//guardar


$("#newsletters").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("/newsletter/getNewsletters", function(result){

        var grid="<br><table id='newsletter_grid'>";
        grid+="<thead><tr><th></th><th>Año</th><th>Mes</th><th>Quincena</th><th></th><th></th><th>Publicado</th></tr></thead>";

         grid+="<tr><td><button id='agregar_button'>Nuevo</button></td></tr>";

         grid+="<tr id='nuevo_field' style='display:none'>";

         grid+=crearNuevaRow();

         grid+="</tr>";



        $.each(result, function(i, elem){

            //show view fieldset, son los campos que se muestran para visualizar los datos

            grid+="<tr id='fieldset_"+elem.id+"'>";

            grid+=mostrarElementosViewMode(elem);               

            grid+="</tr>";


            //hidden field

            grid+="<tr id='fieldset_hidden_"+elem.id+"' style='display:none'>";

            grid+=crearRowHidden(elem);

            grid+="</tr>";


        });

        grid+="</table>";

        $("#grilla").html(grid);


    });




}); 

//crea los elementos editables con el value de su correspondiente existente en modo View o se usa para crear un elemento nuevo

function crearRowHidden(elem){

    var nuevoHiddenFieldSet="";

    nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input type='hidden' value='"+elem.id+"'></td>";

    nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input name='anio' value='"+elem.anio+"'/></td>";

    nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input name='anio' value='"+elem.mes+"'/></td>";

    nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input name='quincena' value='"+elem.quincena+"'/></td>";

    nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><button value='Guardar' name='guardar_newsletter' id='guardar_newsletter_"+elem.id+"' onclick='guardarNewsletter("+elem.id+")'>Guardar</td>";

    nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td></td>";

    if(elem.publicado==1){
        nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='publicado_"+elem.id+"' name='publicado' checked='checked'></td>";
    }else{
        nuevoHiddenFieldSet+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='publicado_"+elem.id+"' name='publicado'></td>";
    }
    return nuevoHiddenFieldSet;

}

function crearNuevaRow(){

    var nuevaRow="";

    nuevaRow+="<td><input type='hidden' value=''></td>";

    nuevaRow+="<td><input name='anio' value=''/></td>";

    nuevaRow+="<td><input name='anio' value=''/></td>";

    nuevaRow+="<td><input name='quincena' value=''/></td>";
//ver que ponerle en id
    nuevaRow+="<td><button value='Guardar' name='guardar_newstletter' id=''>Guardar</td>";

    nuevaRow+="<td></td>";
    //ver que ponerle en id
    nuevaRow+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='' name='publicado'></td>";

    return nuevaRow;

}

//muestra los elementos del listado que se trae de la base de datos

function mostrarElementosViewMode(elem){

    var elemento;

    elemento+="<td><input type='hidden' value='"+elem.id+"'></td>";

    elemento+="<td>"+elem.anio+"</td>";

    elemento+="<td>"+elem.mes+"</td>";

    elemento+="<td>"+elem.quincena+"</td>";

    elemento+="<td><button id='editar_"+elem.id+"' value='Editar' onclick='muestraEditarFields(\""+elem.id+"\")'>Editar</td>";

    elemento+="<td><button id='eliminar_newsletter_"+elem.id+"' value='Eliminar'>Eliminar</td>";

    if(elem.publicado == 1){
        elemento+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='publicado_"+elem.id+"' name='publicado' checked='checked'></td>";
    } else {
        elemento+="<td><input type='checkbox' id='publicado_"+elem.id+"' name='publicado'></td>";
    }

    return elemento;

}
```

});